# Behavior based on condition mentioned by user in scala?

Tags: scala

I have an object Foo

```
object Foo extends RegexParsers{
  def apply(s:String): Array[String] = parseAll(record, line) match {
       // some logic 
      }
   def record = repsep(mainToken, ",")
   // some more code
   def unquotes = "[^,]+".r 
}
```

Now this is pretty hardcoded for comma separated string..

I want to basically modify this function to basically account for another case (tab seperated)..

For which the following code works

```
object Foo extends RegexParsers{
      def apply(s:String): Array[String] = parseAll(record, line) match {
           // some logic 
          }
       def record = repsep(mainToken, "\t") // change here
       // some more code
       def unquotes = "[^\t]+".r  // change here
    }
```

Just two changes...

How do I merge these two changes.. where I can take this delimiter as an argument.. (default argument comma)... and then based on that.. execute the required code.. ??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `Foo` a class instead of an object, and pass the desired separator character as a constructor argument.

```
class Foo(separator: Char) extends RegexParsers {

  def apply(s:String): Array[String] = parseAll(record, line) match {
    // some logic 
  }

  def record = repsep(mainToken, separator.toString)

  def unquotes = ("[^" + separator + "]+").r
}
```

Then use it by making the appropriate instance:

```
// Parser that uses comma as the separator
val foo1 = new Foo(',')

// Parser that uses tab as the separator
val foo2 = new Foo('\t')
```

Comment: @Jesper.. I see a very weird behavior.. when i make the changes.. java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
 at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Apr 15, 2014 1:00:28 PM

Comment: Also... my object is actually object Foo extends RegexParsers

Comment: @Fraz for the first one: put your `main` method in a separate `object` instead of in `class Foo`. And, what stops you from doing `class Foo extends RegexParsers`?

Answer (score 1):

A solution by just adding a var.

This would also work:

```
object Foo extends RegexParsers{
  // make sep a var
  var sep : String = ","
  def apply(s:String): Array[String] = parseAll(record, line) match {
     // some logic 
  }
  def record = repsep(mainToken, sep)
  // some more code
  def unquotes = ("[^" + sep + "]+").r 
}
```

For changing the separator just do:

```
Foo.sep = "\t"
```

But beware no you have added *mutable State* and you could run in problems when the code is run asynchronously or in parallel.